# Execute function on every value of a key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following structure :

```
$array = array(
    array("animal" => "dog","color" => "black"),
    array("animal" => "cat","color" => "white"),
    array("animal" => "mouse","color" => "grey")
);
```

Now I need to execute a function on every value of animal, say make the values uppercase. This is the expected output :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(3) "DOG"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "black"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(3) "CAT"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "white"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(5) "MOUSE"
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "grey"
  }
}
```

When I do

```
for (int i=0; i<=$array.size(); i++) {
    $array["animal"] = array_map('strtoupper', $array["animal"]);
}
```

I get this error:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'i' (T_STRING), expecting ';' in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

Comment: You're for loop is not valid PHP syntax: [PHP for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) - You should check out some PHP-basics. I'm guessing this is a copy/paste from some other language?

Comment: argument at index 1 in array_map must be an array

Comment: and PHP doesnt use `size`, it uses `count($array)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using following ways:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array("animal"=>"dog","color"=>"black"),
     array("animal"=>"cat","color"=>"white"),
     array("animal"=>"mouse","color"=>"grey")
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {

        if($key1 == 'animal'){
            $keys = ucfirst($value1);

            $array[$key][$key1]=$keys;
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_walk Function of PHP

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$array = array(
    array("animal"=>"dog","color"=>"black"),
     array("animal"=>"cat","color"=>"white"),
     array("animal"=>"mouse","color"=>"grey")
    );

$array_map = array_walk($array, 'walk_array');

function walk_array(&$item, $key){

$item['animal'] = strtoupper($item['animal']);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

[image: ScreenShot For Array Walk Function]

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You could use a `for()` loop to iterate through you animals. You'll have to count the number of animals you got first with the `count()` function cast to a variable. Then, you'll be able to make uppercase on your `animal` index with the `strtoupper()` function. Also note that you can use the new PHP syntax for arrays like so `[]` which is a quicker way to do it.

#### Source-code

```
<?php

$animals = [
    [
        'animal' => 'dog',
        'color' => 'black'
    ],

    [
        'animal' => 'cat',
        'color' => 'white'
    ],

    [
        'animal' => 'mouse',
        'color' => 'grey'
    ]
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($animals); $i++)
{
    $animals[$i]['animal'] = strtoupper($animals[$i]['animal']);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($animals);
echo '</pre>';
```

#### Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [animal] => DOG
            [color] => black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [animal] => CAT
            [color] => white
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [animal] => MOUSE
            [color] => grey
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://phpio.net/s/260u).

[PHP : for loop](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

[PHP : count()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

[PHP : strtoupper()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

[PHP : arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).